# Restore Database Wizard not launching

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, restore, ssms

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and trying to use the 'Restore' functionality to copy an existing database into a new one.

This is something I've done a dozen times before, but I'm encountering an unusual problem: the wizard will not launch.  When I select 'Backup' from the Tasks menu, I get the expected 'wait' cursor and a delay before the tool opens, but no other issues.  When I select 'Restore', I don't get the wait cursor, and the wizard doesn't launch (even after 10+ minutes).

I have restarted both SSMS and my PC, this has not resolved the issue.

The only change I've made recently is installing several of Redgate's tools, but 30 minutes of google haven't brought to light any references to this being a known problem.

Can someone recommend a fix for this?

BTW, I have seen [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119816/database-restore-not-working), but it sadly isn't applicable here - the wizard won't open at all, and this is in SSMS 2012, not 2014.

Answer (score 1):

To pinpoint the issue being with your installation of SSMS on your workstation, can you launch management studio on the database server, assuming you have installed it on the server, and, if so, do you get the same behavior?

Comment: No, I'm not able to do it by remoting in.  That said, it was the first time I'd opened SSMS on the server itself, and it loaded in my settings from active directory when I opened it.  This does, however, point to it possibly being a problem with the server itself, not my install...